# array of char is equal to int?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am trying to figure out why an array of char is assigned to a int value, now I am a little confused in using cast operator.

I didn't get what is in do statement, I hope somebody can explain

```
 char *readword()
     {
        int c,i;
        char t[255];
        char *p;

        //jump over chars who aren't letters
        while ((c=getchar())<'A'|| (c>'Z' && c<'a') || c>'z')
           if (c==EOF) return 0;

        i=0;

        do {
             t[i++]=c;// shouldn't be like (char)c
        } while ((c=getchar())>='A' && c<='Z' || c>='a' && c<='z');

        //keep the word in heap memory
        if ( c==EOF)
           return 0;

        t[i++]='\0';

        if ((p=(char *)malloc(i))==0)
        {
           printf(" not enough memory\n");
           exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(p,t);
        return p;
     }
```

Comment: It'll be implicitly truncated down to char. Why need a cast?

Comment: And not the array but it's element is being assigned

Comment: Because C is not Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getchar()` function returns an `int` type; and it is important to use an int to capture the `getchar()` return value.  This is due to if `getchar()` fails, it returns an `(int)(EOF)`*(as per chux comment*.  When it successfully returns, it will return a value that is suitable for a `char`.

The question code is building a `char` string *or array*, one `char` at a time:

```
t[i++]=c;
```

The above line *could* be written:

```
t[i++]=(char)c;
```

Either is suitable due to the compiler automatically converting the first case.

Comment: Minor: `getchar()` returns `EOF`, not necessarily `(int)(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

The mixture of `char` and `int` is fairly simple: `EOF` is intended as a file that can be distinguished from any value you could have read from the file.

To support that, you need to initially read the data from the file into something larger than a `char`, so it can accommodate at least one value that couldn't possibly have come from the file. The type they chose for that purpose was `int`.

So, you read a character from the file, into an `int`. You compare that to `EOF` to see if it's really a character that came from the file or not. If (and only if) you verify that it really came from the file, you save the value into a `char`, because you now know that's what it really represents.

That said, I'd consider it pretty poor code as it stands right now. Just for one particularly obvious example, instead of the `c<'A'|| (c>'Z' && c<'a') || c>'z')` type of code, you almost certainly want to use `isalpha(c)` instead.

It's also a lot easier to do this with `scanf` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any int value to a char. Only the lowest 8 bits will be used. A cast would be more "correct" in terms of communicating your intent - people might not otherwise remember that anything larger than an 8-bit value will get truncated and results are likely to be unexpected.

Note that since you didn't say "unsigned char t[255]" that you actually get 7 bits and the most significant (8th) bit will be interpreted as a *sign*. So for example if you were to say

```
char t = 0xFF;
```

then you would in fact get -1 assigned to t.

If you assign numbers > 0xFF then all bits higher than the 8th bit will get stripped. So if you were to say:

```
char t = 0x101;
```

Than in fact you'd get the value 1 assigned to t.

The code in question is correct because getchar() returns an int and -1 is an error value so it's important to check it. For non-error cases the return will fit in an 8-bit char.